# Как автоматически создавать несколько качеств видео?

Tags: javascript, php, mediaplayer, playerjs

Как автоматически создавать несколько качеств видео? уменя есть видео 720p и мне нужно чтобы php или js создавал на стороне клиента  ещё два 480 и 360. я использую playerjs.com

```
<html>
    <head>              

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.plrjs.com/player/atzn96yz329k9/tou9ijrw9ywl.js"></script>
        <style>html {height: 100%; overflow: hidden;} body {height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; background: black;}</style>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="player" class="UA" style="width:100%;height:100%"></div></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var player = new Playerjs({
                id:"player",
                file:'[720p]https://www.secvideo1.online/get_file/9/1f97f9d2a480bb5780156c9ffc5cf6866cc4763064/529000/529711/529711_720p.mp4,[360p]//Здесь долнжа быть ссылка на  зжатое видео'     }); 
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

или на хостинге автоматически сжимал видео . подскажите как это сделать?  очень надо! спасибо

Comment: Все это можно сделать на стороне сервера с помощью утилиты `ffmpeg`. Думаю эта статья Вам поможет.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34391499/change-video-resolution-ffmpeg

Comment: @phpBear У меня хостинг, может ещё что то есть?

Comment: На стороне клиента это будет фигово, особенно если вы будете отдавать видео с качеством 1080 а клиент его будет урезать до 480. Про наоборот и говорить нечего ;)

Comment: @yurapshow перекодировать на стороне клиента? Это как минимум неэтично. Представьте, что Вы пришли на сайт, а он использует ресурсы Вашего компьютера без Вашего на то согласия - например как это делают js-майнеры.  Так что выход у Вас только один - заливать на хостинг, а там в многопоточном режиме перекодировать. Других вариантов не вижу.

Comment: а как тогда  автоматически создавать качества? на хостинге? возможно есть какойто плагин для dle или для вордпреса . Или ещё какойто цмс?